# Odata service error in XPM

Tags: experience-manager

I am getting internal server error when I am trying to browse OData service.

> ""error":"Internal Server error"

The initial issue was Update preview was not working on XPM. I double checked my lib folder, my config files as well as web.config and all files (Ambient and cartridges in Ambient XML). Even checked the DLLs.

I have re-verified the solutions which are given on other posts but even then this error comes.

Please help me on this and let me know if any information needed from my side.
[image]

Comment: Anything in the EventViewer? Logs?

Comment: Look for warnings (!) from ASP.NET in your Application log under Event Viewer. You will see the real error and hopefully that will lead to easier troubleshooting.

Comment: I have added an image for the log in event viewer.

Comment: Never seen this error. Doublecheck the IIS settings (SessionState), AppPool-settings. Is the latest version of the .NET framework installed? (And used: check AppPool settings)

Comment: WE are facing same problem. Can you please share the solution to your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Arashdeep, though I do not remember it correctly now, but post by Albertromkes (mentioned below) really helped in solving this issue. Please go step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Just check steps on following iconic post, it should resolve your issues.

http://albertromkes.com/2013/01/24/troubleshooting-the-sdl-tridion-experience-manager-with-session-preview/

Comment: I have already re-verified these points as I wrote in my question. Even i set the same on others server which worked fine.

Comment: could you do a folder compare of all the config and jars with folder from working machine? do you see any difference? check logs as well

Comment: Have taken all jars and config from my other machine, have changed my storage file, deployer and licence files. my HTTPUpload worked so i can say my storage file is working fine. I can't find any logs related to this.

Comment: check log path in logback.xml in sessionService' bin\config folder, and check logs.

Comment: If your jars and config match a working one, then your error will have to be related to application server configuration or permissions of the user running the app pool.